# Connecting to wifi wlan0 via script

Tags: scripting, wlan

I am writing a simple script for myself to automatically install Arch-linux.
The below command fails for me:

`printf "$WIFIPASSPHRASE\n" | iwctl station wlan0 connect $WIFINETWORK`

The passphrase will be entered correctly when I execute the script however it is not showing as **** but rather as the actual passphrase.

When I execute the script I get the below in my terminal output:

`Type the network passphrase for _MYWIFI_ psk.`

`Passphrase: _my passphrase_`

`Operation aborted`

Any idea how to fix this or a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Showing where? And why would you expect it to be shown as `***`? You seem to be simply printing it. By the way, you probably want `printf '%s\n' "$WIFIPASSPHRASE"` there.

Comment: No, that didn't work as well. Operation aborted also. In response to your question, normally when I enter the passphrase for the WiFi it will show as ***. I though this might be why this command is failing.

Comment: Yes, the `printf` is just a matter of good practice, it shouldn't make a difference here. But when you "enter the passphrase" and it appears as `***`, that is because you are entering it in a _specific program_ that was written to show it as `*`. It doesn't happen automatically, so it won't be happening in your script. But, again: you still haven't told us _where_ the passphrase appears. In a log? In your terminal output? In the shell history?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the information there.